# Why does bhagwad Gita contradict itself?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, naga, adisesha, vasuki

Bhagwad Gita chapter 10

> आयुधानामहं वज्रं धेनूनामस्मि कामधुक् |
>   प्रजनश्चास्मि कन्दर्प: **सर्पाणामस्मि वासुकि:**।।28।।
>
> I am the Vajra (thunderbolt) amongst weapons and Kamadhenu amongst the cows. I am Kaamdev, the god of love, amongst all causes for procreation; **amongst serpents I am Vasuki.**
>
> **अनन्तश्चास्मि नागानां** वरुणो यादसामहम् |
>   पितृणामर्यमा चास्मि यम: संयमतामहम् || 29||
>
> **Amongst the snakes I am Anant(sheshanag)**; amongst aquatics I am Varun. Amongst the departed ancestors I am Aryama; amongst dispensers of law I am Yamraj, the lord of death.

In one verse, Lord is saying that **I am vasuki among snakes** and in very next verse he is saying that **I am shesha**. Is it a contradiction or my misunderstanding?

**EDIT**: "nagas and sarpas are different" does not seem to be a satisfactory answer because Ananta and Vasuki are brothers (born from same parents). Is it being suggested that out of 2 brothers, one became naga and another became sarpa and both brothers belong to different classes of beings? There is no clarity on this. **Moreover, if someone reads the answer given in the link, it classifies Vasuki as a naaga and not a sarpa.** Therefore, I am voting to reopen the question.

Comment: Nagas and sarpas are different.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Except that Vasuki was younger brother of Ananta.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion Shesha became different from other Nagas/Sarpas due to his tapsya, he lives even beneath Nagaloka/Patala leaving the company of his evil brothers. It is also believed that he got the responsibility to stabilize the earth which earlier held by Brahma/Indra/Vishnu. Vasuki became king only after Sesha left them. So may be Krishna wanted to mention both the imp figures from snakes(Sarpas and/or Nagas).

Comment: sarpa = 1 head, naga = multiple heads. where is the contradiction ?

Comment: the root of the q is to know the diff bw Sarpa and Naga..now whether answer is satisfactory or no answer at all, still the q is duplicate..